# PowerShell task for Azure pipeline fails to load private npm packages

Tags: powershell, azure-pipelines

We have a PowerShell task ("2.*"), that runs `npm install` with try catch to enable retry on failure. However npm install fails when run from this task as it can't access the private feed with custom npm packages.

```
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! Unable to authenticate, need: Bearer authorization_uri=https://login.windows.net/d2...b7, Basic realm="https://pkgsprodcus1.pkgs.visualstudio.com/", TFS-Federated
```

The job has the access to OAuth token by scripts enabled but this doesnt seems to work for PS task.
[image]

What can we do to make the `npm install` run in PS task to install w/o `E401`

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the `$(System.Accesstoken)` here does not available while you `npm install` targeting to azure devops feed registry.

We provide one task which name is [npm Authenticate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/npm-authenticate?view=azure-devops). Why not directly use this task to authorize before you run `npm install` in powershell? In another word, put authorization in one separately task, just do `npm install` in powershell script:

[image]

Just configure one `.npmrc` which at same path level with `package.json` by adding below script:

```
registry=https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/{org}/{project name}/_packaging/{feed name}/npm/registry/
always-auth=true
```